# Get the value of text field (text fidle contains date) using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the value of date in the text field. 
My HTML code:

```
 <table id="sample">
    <tr>
      <td>
          Date
     </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

js file:

```
  $("#sample tr td").after('<td><input type="text" id="datepicker"/></td>').queue(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker();
      $(this).dequeue();
 });
```

I want to alert the date which is given to the textbox.
 JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9r9r8krr/

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) in any action with the selector to select the datepicker element to get its value.

Also not that the [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after) method is a synchronous method so there is no need to use `queue()`

```
$("#sample tr td").after('<td><input type="text" id="datepicker"/></td>');
$('#datepicker').datepicker();

$('button').click(function(){
    alert($('#datepicker').val())
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cmep0gmt/)

Answer (score 2):

Alert the value on change like:

```
$(document).on("change","input", function(){
    if($(this).val()!="") {
      alert($(this).val());
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9r9r8krr/3/)

Answer (score 1):

```
//In below code, you can replace input[type=text] with classname/id of input field. 
$('input[type=text]').on('change', function() {  
    alert($('input[type=text]').val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#sample tr td").after('<td><input type="text" id="datepicker"/></td>').queue(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(date) {
      alert("You selected : " + date);
    }
  });
  $(this).dequeue();
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>



<table id="sample">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Date
    </td>
  </tr>
```

I did not quite get the question but I think you meant this!!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#sample tr td").after('<td><input type="text" id="datepicker"/></td>');
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  onSelect: function(date) {
    alert("You selected : " + date);
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>



<table id="sample">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Date
    </td>
  </tr>
```

This will also work...

Answer (score 0):

try this... working for me!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on("change","input#datepicker", function(){
    if($(this).val()!="") {
      alert($(this).val());
    }
}); });
```